# Multilevel list from Word to Excel

Tags: excel, vba

The result I need is for a multilevel list in MS Word to be spread across columns in excel and then move the the multilevel list indicators into there own columns. Right now my code deletes the multilevel list indicators. I have a solution but it doesn't work for the a. through z. multilevel list indicators because sentences have a letter and period at the end and the code is deleting the last letter of the sentence and the period. I need for the code to select the letter period or number period to the left, the beginning of the string. Also I could not get square brackets  "[ ]" to read as a string and I had to declare each occurrence. Is there a way to identity "[]" as part of a string?
This code copies the multilevel list to the correct columns. I need it to only move the content if the number or letter. Example: 1. or a. or (1) or (a) or [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZGle.png) or [a] are at the beginning of the string.
Here's the code I used to move the cells content according to multilevel list indicator.
The second code I was using to delete the multilevel list after it was moved to the columns.  Ultimately, I would like to move multilevel list indicator into there own column on the same row of their content.
Ultimately, I would like to move the multilevel (Example: 1. or a. or (1) or (a) or [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZGle.png) or [a])into the column next to the content from that level.
Multilevel list in word

[Word list copy and pasted into excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6dzW.png)

1.This is level 1.
a. This is level 2. The last letter and period disappears when I delete the list indicator.
(1) This is level 3.
(a) This is level 4.
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZGle.png) This is level 5. How do I use square brackets in a string.
[a] This is level 6.
1) This is level 7.

[excel desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZGle.png)

```
Sub Findandcut()
Dim row As Long

For row = 1 To 1000

    If Range("A" & row).Value Like "(#)" Then
        ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
        Range("C" & row).Value = Range("A" & row).Value
        Range("A" & row).Value = ""
    End If

    If Range("A" & row).Value Like "[a-z].*" Then
        ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
        Range("B" & row).Value = Range("A" & row).Value
        Range("A" & row).Value = ""
    End If

     If Range("A" & row).Value Like "(#)*" Then
        ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
        Range("C" & row).Value = Range("A" & row).Value
        Range("A" & row).Value = ""
    End If

    If Range("A" & row).Value Like "([a-z])*" Then
        ' Copy the value and then blank the source.
        Range("D" & row).Value = Range("A" & row).Value
        Range("A" & row).Value = ""
    End If

Next
```

End Sub

```
Sub remove_BulletsCol_B()
Dim str1 As String
Dim str2 As String
Dim rngTemp As Range
Dim rngCell As Range
str1 = "a."
str2 = "b."
str3 = "c."
str4 = "d."
str5 = "e."
str6 = "f."
str7 = "g."
str8 = "h."
str9 = "i."
str10 = "j."
str11 = "k."
str12 = "l."
str13 = "m."
str14 = "n."
str15 = "o."
str16 = "p."
str17 = "q."
str18 = "r."
str19 = "s."
str20 = "t."
str21 = "u."
str22 = "v."
str23 = "w."
str24 = "x."
str25 = "y."
str26 = "z."

'Set rngTemp
Set rngTemp = Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion 'You range goes here

'Loop through range and replace string
For Each rngCell In rngTemp

If InStr(1, rngCell, str1) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str1, "")
End If

If InStr(1, rngCell, str2) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str2, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str3) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str3, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str4) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str4, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str5) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str5, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str6) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str6, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str7) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str7, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str8) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str8, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str9) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str9, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str10) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str10, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str11) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str11, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str12) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str12, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str13) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str13, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str14) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str14, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str15) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str15, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str16) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str16, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str17) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str17, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str18) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str18, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str19) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str19, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str20) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str20, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str21) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str21, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str22) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str22, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str23) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str23, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str24) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str24, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str25) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str25, "")
End If
    If InStr(1, rngCell, str26) > 0 Then
    rngCell = Replace(rngCell.Value, str26, "")
End If
```

Next rngCell

End Sub

Comment: To match the special characters left bracket ([) enclose them in brackets. eg Like "[[][a-z]]" 
 [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator).

Comment: Thanks. I could not figure that one out.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Findandcut()

    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, level As Integer
    Dim s As String, n As String, ar
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)
    
    For r = 1 To 1000

        s = Left(ws.Cells(r, "A"), 20)
        If Len(s) > 0 Then
            ' split off the paragrah number
            ar = Split(s, " ")
            n = ar(0)
            level = 0

            ' remove brackets
            If InStr(1, n, "[") Then
                level = 5
                n = Replace(n, "[", "")
                n = Replace(n, "]", "")
            ElseIf InStr(1, n, "(") Then
                level = 3
                n = Replace(n, "(", "")
                n = Replace(n, ")", "")
            ElseIf ar(0) Like "*." Then
                level = 1
                n = Replace(n, ".", "")
            End If
            
            If level > 0 Then
                ' check if n not numeric
                If Not IsNumeric(n) Then
                    level = level + 1
                End If
                ' remove number and move to column
                ws.Cells(r, level + 1) = Mid(s, 2 + Len(ar(0)))
                ws.Cells(r, 1) = ""
            End If
            
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @aimee can you add a screenshot of your input sheet to your question Did you change `Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)` to the correct sheet.

Comment: I added "Word list copy and pasted into excel" which is a link to an screenshot of my input sheet and "excel desired output" is a link to what I am trying to achieve. My sheet name is just "Sheet 1" . I copied and pasted you entire code into a new macro and didn't get any results.

Comment: You were right, my sheet was named wrong, but still not the desired outcome. I used the [[] to move the brackets instead of the "[" which moved the square bracket rows. I am still losing the last two letters of text and the first and second level didn't move.

Comment: @Aimee I think it is the indenting, add trim to this line like this `s = Left(Trim(ws.Cells(r, "A")), 20)`

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured it out.